# Unable to validate Angular 6 this.fb.array

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to implement validations to my checkbox FormBuilder.array but despite checking one of the boxes, the form will still be invalid.

I've tried `Validators.required` and `Validators.requiredTrue` but it still doesn't work as expected

TS:

```
this.Form = this.fb.group({
  stage: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-check-label">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="none" value="1" #noneChk
      (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.stage)">
    Stage 1
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check-label">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="self" value="2" #selfChk
      (change)="onCheckArray($event, Form.value.stage)">
    Stage 2
  </label>
</div>

<p>{{ this.Form.valid | json }}</p>
```

I have my StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hv9njj)

Comment: Mhfour, Validators.required not work in a formArray because the value of a FormArray is always "something" -an array-. You need make a custom validator that check if one element of the formArray is checked

Comment: to understand a checkbox, check this question of stackblitz. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619632/angular-formarray-checkboxes/56622210#56622210. NOTE: If you want use the custom form control, but not want use material, just replace in check-boxlist-component `<mat-checkbox [formControl]="check">{{key?_data[i][text]:_data[i]}}</mat-checkbox>` by `<label><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="check">{{key?_data[i][text]:_data[i]}}</label>`

Comment: is there an example for the custom validations? i tried a few but it didnt work

Comment: I add an answer to make a custom validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your stackblitz, I [forked your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdunjk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The problem is that your function onCheckArray don't change the FormArray (yes, you changed the value, but not the FormArray, so there was any validation. See your function edited

```
//I repite the getter stage, so the answer can be understood

get stage(): FormArray {
  return this.Form.get('stage') as FormArray;
}

onCheckArray(event) { //you needn't send the value
    /* Selected */
    if (event.target.checked) {
      // Add a new control in the arrayForm, 
      // use push, but add a new FormControl TO the formArray
      this.stage.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
    } else {
      /* unselected */
      // find the unselected element
      let i: number = 0;

       //we iterate over the formArray
      for (i = 0; i < this.stage.value.length; i++) {
        if (this.stage.value[i] == event.target.value) {
          //use removeAt(i)
          this.stage.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Well, your function validators can be more easy, just check the length of the array

```
minSelectedCheckboxes(min = 1) {
    return (formArray: FormArray) => {
      return formArray.controls.length >= min ? null : { required: true };
    };
```

}

And there are a problem if you initialize the FormArray

```
this.Form = this.fb.group({
  stage: this.fb.array([new FormControl("3")], this.minSelectedCheckboxes())
})
```

Your .html must be like

```
 <div class="form-check-label">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="none" value="1" #noneChk 
          <!--see how indicate when is checked-->
          [checked]="stage.value.indexOf('1')>=0"
           (change)="onCheckArray($event)">
      1
    </label>
  </div>
```

Well, I you are asking about a more simple way to manage an array of checkboxes, we can take another aproach. Our FormArray will be an array of controls with value true/false, and we has a function taht transform this array in our values.

```
  options=["1","2","3","4"]; //our options
  get valuesSelected() ; //a function that return the options selected
  {
      return this.options.filter((x,index)=>this.newForm.get('stage').value[index])
  }
  //see how create the formArray, always has the same number of 
  //elements that our options

  this.newForm=new FormGroup({
        stage:new FormArray(this.options
             .map(x=>new FormControl(false)),this.minTrueCheckboxes())
  })

  minTrueCheckboxes(min = 1) {
    return (formArray: FormArray) => {
      return formArray.value.filter(x=>x).length>=min? null : { required: true };
    };
  }
```

And our .html becomes like

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="newForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName="stage">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let control of newForm.get('stage').controls;let i=index">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" [formControl]="control" >
          {{options[i]}}
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

<p>{{ valuesSelected | json }}</p>
```

Comment: thanks so much it works now! just wondering, if i want the checkboxes to be empty by default, how do i do that? i removed the value 3 from the formControl in fb.array but the initial value will be null, how do i make it empty?

Comment: `stage: this.fb.array([], this.minSelectedCheckboxes())`, just an empty array

Answer (score 0):

A custom validator can be make in the own component
or outside.

You can see the two models in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfaduf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
//In the own component
this.form = new FormGroup({
      checks: new FormArray([
        new FormControl(true),
        new FormControl(false),
      ], this.AtLeatOne()), //sii that call it as this.AtLeastOne
    });

AtLeatOne() {
    return (control: FormArray) => {
      if (control.value.find(x => x))
        return null
      return { "error": "You must select at least one option" }
    }
  }

//OutSide
    this.form2 = new FormGroup({
      checks: new FormArray([
        new FormControl(true),
        new FormControl(false),
      ], AtLeatOneValidator())
    });

export function AtLeatOneValidator()
{
  return (control: FormArray)=> {
      if (control.value.find(x => x))
        return null
      return { "error": "You must select at least one option" }
  }
}
```

Well, I put the most general case for if we want to send an argument to the function (Imagine we want that the user select al least 2 options.)

Comment: hi i tried this but could not work. for my case, i use the Form.value.whateverControlName and use that as the array. is there a custom validator that can be applied to that?

Comment: @mhfour, I can't see the form in your .html. take a look to the stackblitz of my answer if you want to see an example, and update your question with the .html

Comment: hi, i just added my stackblitz to my question. would greatly appreciate the help