# how to give mat-select option a dynamic object key as a value?

Tags: angular, angular-material

i want to pass a dynamic object to mat-select component and also pass the input key of object , that should be used in `[value]` by mat-option.
here mat-select

```
<mat-select [placeholder]="field.label" [formControlName]="field.name">
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of field.options" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

in place of item it should be dynamically object key .e.g
if i pass this array like to iterate

```
[{name:'hassa',id:1}]
```

for loop and i want to pass `id` as use in `[value]="item"` in `mat-option`
  but it should be dynamic object can be changed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyvalue pipe -similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51491848/1029688

```
<mat-select formControlName="example">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of testObject | keyvalue" [value]="item.key">
        Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some like

```
//in .ts
key="id"
text="name"

<mat-option *ngFor="let item of field.options" 
      [value]="item[key]">
   {{item[text]}}
</mat-option>
```

If you want to make a custom component to mannage a list of check box, take a look to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619632/angular-formarray-checkboxes/56622210#56622210)

Comment: it will give the value of key not the key i think

Answer (score -1):

You need to use displayWith attribute in mat-autocomplete tag