# Can we convert formArray data into comma separated string, Example at index 0:["1,3,4,6"]

Tags: angular

Lets say i have a checkbox and each checkbox has a categoryId. When i check the checkbox i will get the categoryId and each data will be save as a formArray, example at index 0: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMwYN.png),1:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPyEC.png),2:[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VokM7.png),3:[6] . So this is the data i currently get but my question is instead of storing the data at different index number i want to get the result as index 0:["1,3,4,6"] as array of string. I want to store the data only in index 0 in other words i want to store all the checkbox categoryId only in one index as a string. I'll share my code below.
This is the code that i used to get the categoryId from checkbox

```
onChange(categoryId: string[], isChecked: boolean) {
  debugger
  const categoryIdArray = (this.patientReportForm.controls.hubxCategoryId as FormArray);
  if (isChecked) {
    categoryIdArray.push(new FormControl(categoryId)) 
  } else {
    let index = categoryIdArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == categoryId)
    categoryIdArray.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

This is formcontrol

```
this.patientReportForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      patientId : new FormControl(Number(this.clientId)),
      hubxCategoryId : this.formBuilder.array([]),
      notes : new FormControl(),
    })
```

this is my html section for checkbox

```
 <div *ngFor="let hubxReport of hubxReportList; let i=index">
                <div class="lineheader  "> 
                  <section class="" [formGroup]="patientReportForm">
                    <p><mat-checkbox color="primary" (change)="onChange(hubxReport.categoryId, $event.checked)">{{hubxReport.categoryName}}</mat-checkbox></p>
                  </section>
                </div>
```

this is the data i currently get
[image: current result]

and this is the result i want to get
[image: expected result]

my final result here patientid is null. Below i'm assigning patientid : this.clientid. when i debug and i check it, this.clientid carries a value 40.But when i submit patientid shows null

```
patientReportForm=this.getGroup({patientId : this.clientId ,hubxCategoryId:"",notes:""})
```

[image: result]

here this.clientid carries value 40.
[image: debug image]

Comment: can you help me with the logic

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  convertValue(){
    const values = this.form.get('hubxCategoryId').value;

    //values is an array [true,true,false,...]
    return this.hubxReport
            //filter gets [{hubxCategoryId:2,categoryName:".."},
            //             {hubxCategoryId:6,categoryName:".."},..]
           .filter((x, index) => values[index]) 

            //maps return only the "Id" [2,6,...]
           .map(x=>x.hubxCategoryId)
           
            //join return an string "2,6,..."
           .join(",")
  }
```

But take a look to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619632/angular-formarray-checkboxes/56622210#56622210), you not create a FormArray else a FormControl that store an array

**Update** step by step

Imagine you has

```
hubxReportList=[{hubxCategoryId:1,categoryName:'Marka'}, 
                 {hubxCategoryId:2,categoryName:'Kilometraza'},
                 {hubxCategoryId:3,categoryName:'Alu felne'}]
```

You can to have a function like

```
  getGroup(data:any=null)
  {
    data=data || {patienID:0,hubxCategoryId :"",notes:""}
  
    const list=data.hubxCategoryId?data.hubxCategoryId.split(',').map(x=>+x):[]
    return new FormGroup({
      patienID:new FormControl<number>(data.patienID),
      hubxCategoryId :new FormArray(this.hubxReportList.map(x=>new FormControl(list.indexOf(x.hubxCategoryId)>0))),
      notes:new FormControl<string>(data.notes)
    }) 
  }

//and use 
patientReportForm2=this.getGroup(
             {patienID:0,hubxCategoryId:"1,3",notes:""})
//or 
patientReportForm2=this.getGroup()
```

As always we have a FormArray we use a getter

```
  get hubxCategoryIdArray()
  {
    return this.patientReportForm2.get('hubxCategoryId') as FormArray
  }
```

And the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="patientReportForm" (submit)="submit(patientReportForm)">
  <div class="lineheader" formArrayName="hubxCategoryId">
    <section
      class=""
      *ngFor="let control of hubxCategoryIdArray.controls; let i = index"
    >
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" color="primary" [formControlName]="i" />
        {{ hubxReportList[i].categoryName }}
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

The function submit like

```
  submit(form:FormGroup)
  {
    if (form.valid)
    {
      const data:any={...form.value};
      data.hubxCategoryId=this.hubxReportList
           .filter((x, index) => form.value.hubxCategoryId[index]) 
           .map(x=>x.hubxCategoryId)
           .join(",")

      console.log(data)
    }
  }
```

Another option is really use a FormControl, not a FormArray that store an string separated by commas

```
  getGroup(data:any=null)
  {
    data=data || {patienID:0,hubxCategoryId :"",notes:""}
  
    return new FormGroup({
      patienID:new FormControl(data.patienID),
      hubxCategoryId :new FormControl(data.hubxCategoryId ),
      notes:new FormControl(data.notes)
    })
  }
```

We use ngModel inside a FormGroup

```
<div *ngFor="let hubxReport of hubxReportList; let i = index">
  <div class="lineheader">
    <section class="">
      <p>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          color="primary"
          [ngModel]="
            (patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId')?.value || [])
                .split(',').indexOf(
                    '' + hubxReport.hubxCategoryId
                 ) >= 0
             "
          (ngModelChange)="onChange(hubxReport.hubxCategoryId, $event)"
          [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
        />
        {{ hubxReport.categoryName }}
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the function onChange

```
 onChange(categoryId:any,checked:boolean)
  {
     let newValue:string
     const oldValue:string=this.patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId').value
     const oldArray=oldValue?oldValue.split(',').map(x=>+x):[] 
     if (checked)
     newValue=this.hubxReportList
              .filter((x) =>  x.hubxCategoryId==categoryId || oldArray.indexOf(x.hubxCategoryId)>=0) 
              .map(x=>x.hubxCategoryId)
              .join(",")     
  
      else
      newValue=this.hubxReportList
              .filter((x) =>  x.hubxCategoryId!=categoryId && oldArray.indexOf(x.hubxCategoryId)>=0) 
              .map(x=>x.hubxCategoryId)
              .join(",")     
  
              console.log(oldArray,newValue)

        this.patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId').setValue(newValue)
  }
```

```
  onChange(categoryId:any,checked:boolean)
  {
     let newValue:string
     const oldValue:string=this.patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId').value
     const oldArray=oldValue?oldValue.split(',').map(x=>+x):[] 
     if (checked)
     newValue=this.hubxReportList
              .filter((x) =>  x.hubxCategoryId==categoryId || oldArray.find(y=>y==x.hubxCategoryId)) 
              .map(x=>x.hubxCategoryId)
              .join(",")     
  
      else
      newValue=this.hubxReportList
              .filter((x) =>  x.hubxCategoryId!=categoryId && oldArray.find(y=>y==x.hubxCategoryId)) 
              .map(x=>x.hubxCategoryId)
              .join(",")     
  
        this.patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId').setValue(newValue)
  }
```

In this case we needn't make anything in submit

You can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5hfre8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) both case

BONUS: we can create a custom form control like the link I indicate, in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4alof-mkpcqf?file=main.ts) is improve the code to mannage an string separated by commas

Comment: thanks for the effort, can you help me with a stackblitz code

Comment: @user16780164, I update the answer (sorry for the delay)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. this is what i expected. but there is one problem i have categoryId 11,1,2,27,4,6,28 and so on. When i check first checkbox automatically it check two checkbox that is (categoryId 11 and 1)and when i check the third checkbox it works fine(only check one checkbox) but again when i check 4th checkbox it again check two checkbox automatically. What might be the issue

Comment: @user16780164, ::glups:: yes, you need change the "indexOf" by "find", I updated the stackblitz and the answer

Comment: issue is still there, when i check checkbox with category 11 automatically it checks checkbox with category id 1 and when i check checkbox with category 27 it autmatically checks checkbox with category 7

Comment: sorry again (and apologies for your time spended), yes, I forgot a "split" in ngModel `[ngModel]="(patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId')?.value || []).split(',').indexOf('' + hubxReport.hubxCategoryId) >= 0"`

Comment: having this error "((intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) || jit___pureFunction0_12(...)).split is not a function". im using angular 12

Comment: you're going to kill me :( `(patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId')?.value || '').split(',')`

Comment: thanks for the help i need to ask one help in this code patientReportForm=this.getGroup({patientId : this.clientId ,hubxCategoryId:"",notes:""})
getGroup(data:any=null)
{
  data=data || {patientId : this.clientId,hubxCategoryId :"",notes:""}
  return new FormGroup({
    patientId:new FormControl(this.clientId),
    hubxCategoryId :new FormControl(data.hubxCategoryId),
    notes:new FormControl(data.notes)
  })
} here i assigned patientId : this.clientId. here when i debug and check this.client has a value 40 but when i submit patientId shows null what might be the issue

Comment: **not** use `this.clientIdp  inside the function else `data.patientId` -really you can do it, but the idea of the function is that you pass an object with properties patientId,hubxCategoryId and notes. write at first `console.log(data)` to see what value has and check if your'e write "patient" or "patien". The code is a typical to can call to the function `myfor=this.getGroup()` or `myfor=this.getGroup(object)` -where object is a variable that is an object- or `myform=this.getGroup({patientId : this.clientId ,hubxCategoryId:"",notes:""})`. Should be work

Comment: myform=this.getGroup({patientId : this.clientId ,hubxCategoryId:"",notes:""}) .  I have given this code still patientid carries null data. I added an image of the result above and i have also added the image for this.clientid data that i see while debugging.Please check the at the above

Comment: any suggestion this.clientId issue is still there

Comment: hello Elisio can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74077495/can-we-loop-the-autotable-body-and-header-to-print-multiple-data-dynamically-acc

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `let desiredFormat= this.patientReportForm.value.hubxCategoryId.join(",")`

Comment: how can i call desiredFormat here hubxCategoryId : this.formBuilder.array([]) , currently data is showing from this line of code  if (isChecked) {
    categoryIdArray.push(new FormControl(categoryId)) 
  }